# Why list comprehension doesn't work in case of list whih is result of os.walk function?

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

In result of os.walk function I get this list which contain names of files in folder:

```
['tr-02-10-18.pdf', 'tr-02-11-18.pdf', 'tr-02-12-18.pdf', 'tr-03-11-18.pdf', 'tr-03-12-18.pdf', 'tr-04-10-18.pdf', 'tr-04-11-18.pdf', 'tr-04-12-18.pdf']
```

My goal is to bring the list to that form:

```
['tr/02/10/18.pdf', 'tr/02/11/18.pdf','tr/02/12/18.pdf', 'tr/03/11/18.pdf', 'tr/03/12/18.pdf', 'tr/04/10/18.pdf', 'tr/04/11/18.pdf', 'tr/04/12/18.pdf']
```

I've tried to use code as seen below:

```
import os
for file_name in os.walk(input()):
    egg1=(str(file_name[-1]))
    egg2= []
    for mark in egg1:
        mark=[i.replace("-","/") for i in mark]
        egg2.append(mark)
print(egg2)
```

What I got is this list:

```
[['['], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['2'], ['/'], ['1'], ['0'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['2'], ['/'], ['1'], ['1'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['2'], ['/'], ['1'], ['2'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['3'], ['/'], ['1'], ['1'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['3'], ['/'], ['1'], ['2'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['4'], ['/'], ['1'], ['0'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['4'], ['/'], ['1'], ['1'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [','], [' '], ["'"], ['t'], ['r'], ['/'], ['0'], ['4'], ['/'], ['1'], ['2'], ['/'], ['1'], ['8'], ['.'], ['p'], ['d'], ['f'], ["'"], [']']]
```

P.S. This is my first question ever, so sorry for any inconsistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several mistakes:

1. `os.walk()` produces a tuple of 3 elements, the path to the current directory, a list of filenames and a list of directory names. You named the tuple `file_name`:

   ```
   for file_name in os.walk(input()):
   ```

   Better to split that out into separate components, so `for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(...):`. Since you ignore the first two arguments, you can also use `for *_, filenames in os.walk(...):`
2. You turned the list of filenames into a single string:

   ```
   egg1=(str(file_name[-1]))
   ```

   `file_name[-1]` is the list of filenames. You turned the *list* into a string, so now you have string representations and `[`, `]` and `,` comma characters:

   ```
   >>> egg1
   "['tr-02-10-18.pdf', 'tr-02-11-18.pdf', 'tr-02-12-18.pdf', 'tr-03-11-18.pdf', 'tr-03-12-18.pdf', 'tr-04-10-18.pdf', 'tr-04-11-18.pdf', 'tr-04-12-18.pdf']"
   ```

   You then take each individual character from the above string and replaced dashes with slashes. Don't turn lists into strings, iterate directly over the list.
3. You *replace* the `egg2` list with a new, empty list for each directory. Create the list *before* the `os.walk()` loop.
4. You put the result of each `str.replace()` call into a new list with a single element, to then append that list to the `egg2` list. Don't add more lists.

This code works:

```
result = []

for *_, filenames in os.walk(input()):
    for filename in filenames:
        replaced = filename.replace('-', '/')
        result.append(replaced)
```

This can be combined into a list comprehension:

```
result = [f.replace('-', '/') for *_, fs in os.walk(input()) for f in fs]
```